# How to get in a variable the geometry type from leaflet draw tool bar

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using Leaflet draw plugin in my Angular app which already has leaflet installed.

I´d like to get in a variable if the selected geometry in the toolbar is a point, a line, a polygon etc.

In the angular component I have this function to get the coordinates, but I need to know the geometry:

```
this.globals.map.addControl(drawControl).on('click',onClick);
    function onClick(e) {
        var lat;
        var lng;
        var coordsPair=[]
        lat=e.latlng.lat;
        lng=e.latlng.lng
        coordsPair.push(lat,lng)
        polygon.push(coordsPair);
        coordsPair=[];
        console.log(polygon);
    }
}
```

Now I can only get the coords  but I can´t get the geometry type clicking on the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this, I am not sure if this the best solution, but it works.

I get drawControl in a variable:

```
drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.polygon.handler._markers
```

And then, clicking on the map I can control the geometry doing this:

```
if(drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.polygon.handler._markers!=undefined){
         polygonButton=drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.polygon.handler._markers[counter]._latlng;
          lat=polygonButton.lat;
         lng=polygonButton.lng;
         geometry='POLYGON'
      }else if(drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.polyline.handler._markers!=undefined){
        polylineButton=drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.polyline.handler._markers[counter]._latlng;
        lat=polylineButton.lat;
        lng=polylineButton.lng;
        geometry="LINESTRING"
      } else if(drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.marker.handler._marker!=undefined){
        markerButton=drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.marker.handler._marker._latlng;
        lat=markerButton.lat;
        lng=markerButton.lng;
        geometry="POINT"
      }
```

If you have selected a geometry _marker has the coordinates, the others don´t, so on this way you can control the selected geometry.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used leaflet.draw, but I think you want to listen for [draw:created](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event-draw:created) events. I think that event gives you the type of layer that was created.

I forked someone's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/a1uz3n2L/2/) and hooked up to the draw:created event to test and the event does appear to give you the type as a string as well as the created object.

```
{layer: i, layerType: "polyline", type: "draw:created", target: i, sourceTarget: i}
{layer: i, layerType: "polygon", type: "draw:created", target: i, sourceTarget: i}
```